# Get OS X Terminal.app to accept Ctrl-+ for Vim

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, hotkeys, macvim

I am trying to bind <kbd>Ctrl-+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl--</kbd> in Vim to resize the current window. However, Terminal does not seem to pass anything when I press <kbd>Ctrl-+</kbd>. <kbd>Ctrl--</kbd> *does* work.

I checked in Vim itself using <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> and in Bash using `cat -v`. No luck. Disabling the hotkeys for OS X's Spaces is no use, either.

MacVim seems to have the same problem. Is this a reserved hotkey for OS X, perhaps?

Comment: If you open *Keyboard Viewer* from the *Input menu* you can enable in *System Preferences » Language & Text » Input Sources*, you'll notice that pressing `Ctrl` will prevent `Shift` from taking hold. This is why on my British keyboard, `Ctrl-Minus` and `Ctrl-Shift-Minus` both produce `^_`. Unfortunately, switching to a different keyboard layout with `+` on its own, unmodified key, such as German, doesn't help either. But other applications, such as *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts* or third party applications such as [Butler](http://manytricks.com) receive `Cmd-+` just fine.

Comment: Daniel: thank you, I had not gotten that far. FWIW, I am using an external non-Apple USB "International" and the MBP's internal US keyboard. Both keyboards give the same results. I would not even mind the "non-shiftiness" if `Ctrl-=` (a.k.a. `Ctrl-+` minus the shift) worked — but even that combination does not get through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not actually a key combination (`Ctrl-Minus`) you enter, but a [UNIX control code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) -- like what happens when you enter `^D` or `^C` ([caret notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation)). That's why `cat -v` displays it as `^_`.

There's just no control code associated with `Ctrl-Plus` or `Ctrl-Equals`. It just doesn't work like you want:  you're actually assigning a command to ASCII character `0x1F`.

Comment: Thank you! I will try and see if I can make Terminal.app pass along some other (as of yet unused) sequence using its keyboard mapping. Too bad I would have to do that for every terminal application I use Vim with, though.